# Stop terminal command once output reaches a certain size?

Tags: linux, terminal

If I want to run `somecommand > somefile` but stop it once `somefile` reaches a certain size, how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
somecommand | dd bs=1K count=2 iflag=fullblock > somefile
```

This will write exactly 2 KiB to the file (less if `somecommand` terminates first). `iflag=fullblock` is not required by POSIX, your `dd` may not support it, the command containing `iflag=fullblock` is not portable. Compare [this scenario](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/473464/108618) to see why it may be important.

After processing the right number of blocks (`count=2` in the above example) `dd` terminates, this breaks the pipe. It's up to `somecommand` how it reacts to a broken pipe. See this: [What makes a Unix process die with broken pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84813/108618)

If the amount of bytes you want to keep forces you to use some inconvenient `bs` and/or `count`, consider this:

```
somecommand | { dd bs=1M count=1024 iflag=fullblock; dd bs=10 count=1 iflag=fullblock; } > somefile
```

The command will write 1 GiB (=1024 MiB) plus 10 bytes.

Some implementations of `head` allow you to use `-c` option to get an arbitrary number of bytes. This is also not portable, the option is not required by POSIX.

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278465/108618) `dd` with an input block size of 1 (`ibs=1`) is the only POSIX way to read an exact number of bytes.

If `somecommand` generates textual output and you want to limit the number of lines in the file, `head` is the right tool though. This will save the first 5 lines only (again, less if `somecommand` terminates first):

```
somecommand | head -n 5 > somefile
```

The `-n` option of `head` is required by POSIX.

Comment: You got in ahead of me this time!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I assume the "bs=1K count=2" part means basically "2 instances of 1 KiB"?

Comment: @SilasReel Yes. `man dd` is your friend. :)

Comment: Does this stop the source command or does it just ignore extra output (AFAIK `head` does the latter)?

Comment: @xenoid It's up to `somecommand` how it reacts to a broken pipe. See this: [What makes a Unix process die with Broken pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84813/108618). In my Debian `head` does terminate, so it breaks the pipe.